# Regex in the Symfony annotation configuration

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony5

I am trying to use regex in the directory path of the annotations for the controllers. File: `config/routes/annotations.yaml`.

E.g. the original config line is `resource: ../../src/Controller/` and I want to modify it to something like `resource: ../../src/*/Controller/`.

If I am looking at the right class that loads this configuration it seems that they are using a `file_exists` check which makes the use of regex impossible. Am I missing something, is this doable or should I look for another solution?

Comment: Maybe **resource: '../src/'** will be enaugh.

Comment: @fbuchlak Hmm this seems to work, but I am afraid it will load too many files in order to process only the routes. I might go with this if I don't manage to find another option.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a regex for a resource, that regex should match a list of files and not a list of directories. The correct configuration is this:

```
resource: '../../src/*Controller/*'
```

If you want to be more specific:

```
resource: '../../src/*Controller/*Controller.php'
```

If you want to match any level of subdirectories:

```
resource: '../../src/**/*Controller.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set resource for directory and exclude directories in it.

```yaml
# services.yaml
resource: '../src/'
exclude:
    - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
    - '../src/Entity/'
    - '../src/Kernel.php'
    - '../src/Tests/'
```